# chrome.storage.sync.get always returns default value

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension and it requires me to keep track of the last date that the extension was run. To do so, I am using chrome.storage.sync, however, the get call always returns the value that I have set as the default. Below is the code.

```js
 chrome.storage.sync.get({theDate: {}}, function (dateResult) {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    let setDate = dateResult.theDate; // always set to {}
    if (Object.keys(setDate).length === 0){ //if date has never been set before
        setDate = currentDate;
    }
    if (setDate.toLocaleDateString() !== currentDate.toLocaleDateString()){
          //do stuff if it is a different day than the last time extension was run
    }


    chrome.storage.sync.set({theDate: currentDate}, function () {
        console.log("Current date set.");

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome extension storage API supports only JSON-compatible types such as strings, numbers, booleans, and arrays/objects that consist of those primitive types.

A `Date` object isn't JSON'ifiable so it can't be stored.
You can store `Date.now()` which is a number.

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get({theDate: Date.now()}, ({theDate}) => {
  if (new Date(theDate).toLocaleDateString() !== new Date().toLocaleDateString()) {
    // do stuff if it is a different day than the last time extension was run
  }
  chrome.storage.sync.set({theDate: Date.now()});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what you can store in chrome.storage. Since I only needed to know if it was the same date, I stored new Date().toLocaleDateString() rather than the entire object, which is the same idea detailed here with Date.now()

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify the `Date` objects before storing them. Use `JSON.stringify` or the `String` constructor. Alternatively, you can call `Date` as a normal function rather than a constructor to get string objects rather than a Unix Time Stamp; or, better yet as [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55273892/6837399) suggests, use `Date.now()` to get the date as a number in milliseconds. [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

I must also note that in the first conditional, you check if the `Date` object retrieved from storage has any keys, but it should not, even if you could store the raw `Date` object. You may be misunderstanding how data is set in storage. Essentially `dateResult === {theDate: currentDate}`, and `dateResult.theDate === currentDate`. [2](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-sync)

edit: include wOxxOm's suggestion for completeness.